# getmac ERROR: Invalid class

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, mac-address

When trying to run `getmac` from the Windows Command Prompt, I am getting `ERROR: Invalid class`. As a Windows utility, I'm not entirely sure why it's broken or how to go about fixing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the exact command you are typing?

Comment: Just `getmac`, no arguments

Comment: [getmac error invalid namespace](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/3e9c4afb-976e-4f04-8950-699fe39614f0/getmac-error-invalid-namespace?forum=ITCG) looks like a possiblity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) is not running on your system or you don't have permissions.

You can download the WMI Diagnosis utility at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=D7BA3CD6-18D1-4D05-B11E-4C64192AE97D

If this utility helps, perfect, you do not need to do anything now. If not, you need to repair the OS so that the desired application gets installed properly.

Hope this help.